# Is it possible to generate an AWS access key via IAM for use with the Product Advertising API?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api, amazon-iam

I like using IAM (Identity and Access Management) to create users/groups with specific permissions for specific purposes.

The Product Advertising API requires use of an access key (request param is [AWSAccessKeyId](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CommonRequestParameters.html)) and IAM can generate access keys, but I don't see a way to give IAM users/groups access to **only** the Product Advertising API.

Anyone know if this can be done? Or do you know of a workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Update

Reading the mentioned thread [IAM policies for Amazon Product API](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=79313) entirely reveals, that the questioner actually tried to to just that, i.e. use IAM access keys to access the Product Advertising API, but apparently to no avail. So I'm afraid the mentioned [AWS team response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289929#289929) has to be taken literally and your use case is not covered yet by IAM, unfortunately.

---

#### Initial Answer

[AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) doesn't currently support the [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) (see the AWS team response to [IAM policies for Amazon Product API](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289929#289929)), but assuming the IAM access keys as such do work there as well, you could deny your users/groups access to **every other** AWS service supporting IAM by means of a respective [IAM policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html) at least (which should cover the majority of critical ones). The recommended [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) can help in crafting a respective policy, which might actually be as simple as this (I just selected *Effect -> Deny* and checked the *AWS Service -> All Services* checkbox):

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1331670627168",
      "Action": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I actually create a user and a group for "Product Advertising API". Initially, I assign a policy for this test group, but I remove the policy right after the group is created. So you could manage a group which has no policy for Product Advertising API. Still, "Product Advertising API" is not in the IAM policy!

Answer (score 2):

As Amazon Product API [isn't yet covered by IAM Policies](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289929#289929), one can expect that it shall be enough to have a user without any policy attached because [default is to deny](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html). (In other words, for such user everything will be denied except for Product API which is not protected by IAM.)

But that's not true. Whatever I tried I only could access the API with my root key. (To avoid security implications I decided to register an additional account with no credit card attached.)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Product API **DOES** work with IAM.

I created an IAM user. It's not in a group and has no roles. I only attached "AdministratorAccess" policy to it. I tested it in "ItemSearch" and "CartCreate" operations. It's working very well.

You can also create a new deny policy to restrict the user access to other services as described by byronicM here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=289929#289929

Comment: I've independently come to the same conclusion as byronicM in the link here - give a user AdministrationAccess and explicitly Deny all services individually. Given the only alternative is to use root keys which are not restricted in any way, this seems to be a safer approach (if initial experimentation pans out)

Answer (score 1):

This was quietly added earlier this year ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/use-your-existing-aws-security-credentials-for-the-product-advertising-api.html)). Use this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ProductAdvertisingAPI:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until Amazon supports this, it is recommended you to create a separate full key and delete them later when you are done with development. So, first production key is not exposed and won't need change, that will save you time.